# How do I route to a different page in Vue when I do print?

Tags: vue.js, printing, vue-router

I am trying to set up a print version of a page.  The page looks significantly different that using CSS media queries meant duplicating the whole content.

So I was wondering is it possible to set it up such that when I do

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
- `window.print()` from a link
- "Share" to printer on Safari mobile

to use a different route?

I was thinking of using the `beforeprint` `afterprint` events but that kind of screwed up my routing.

```
// in the original content
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", () => {
  router.push("/print");
});

// in the print route
window.addEventListener("afterprint", () => {
  router.go(-1);
});
```

Comment: I don't see any other way to do that, what's wrong with this solution? It just messes with the route history?

Comment: yeah, depends on the browser if I do it on Edge/Chrome it's okay, on mobile safari it breaks and firefox.